# Python - Why can't attributes of inherited object be deleted?

Tags: python, inheritance

Why can't attributes of inherited object be deleted?

```
class A(object):
    def delete(self):
        pass
    def dont_delete(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    pass

del A.delete
del B.dont_delete
AttributeError: dont_delete
```

Comment: Class `B` does not have an attribute `dont_delete`, thus you can't delete it.

Comment: You can delete attributes of inherited objects, but this is not an attribute of B, it's an attribute of A. When you have the actual instance you can easily do it with `self`

Comment: @l4mpi hasattr(b, "dont_delete") True

Comment: @Manoj: but `'dont_delete' in B.__dict__` is false. `hasattr()` includes inherited attributes (any attribute for which `getattr()` will work returns True when tested for with `hasattr()`).

Comment: All right, so hasattr() searches through the entire hierarchy structure but del looks up only `B.__dict__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dont_delete` is not copied over to `B`; you can only delete *direct attributes* from objects.

Python looks up attributes on instances and classes by delegating down the chain of inheritance, not by copying attributes across to sub-classes. As such there is nothing to delete from a subclass either.

You should not try and 'uninherit'; when are using `A` as a base class, you are effectively stating that `B` is the same thing as `A`, only more specialised. That process only ever should *add* attributes, not remove. Design your classes accordingly; use a mixin base class for attributes and methods that should not always be inherited, for example.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks a lot, but I'm not sure why you downvoted my question. Not everyone knows everything!

Comment: @Manoj: I did not vote on your question, actually. Instead, I answered it.